# Apache + mod_wsgi interaction

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Before posting this, I have read quite a few resources online, including the [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading) wiki, but I am confused about how exactly Apache processes/threads interact with mod_wsgi.

This is my current understanding: Apache can be configured to run such that one or more child processes can handle incoming requests, and each of these child processes can be configured to in turn use one or more threads to service requests. After that, things start getting hazy for me. My doubts are:

1. What is a WSGIDaemonProcess, and who actually calls my Django app using the python sub interpreter?
2. If I have my Django app running under a mode where multiple threads are allowed in a single Apache child process - does that mean that multiple requests could be simultaneously accessing my app at the same time? If so - would doing something like setting a module level variable (say that of an user's ID) could be over-written by other parallel requests and lead to non-thread safe behavior?
3. For the case above, with Python's global interpreter lock, would the threads actually be executing in parallel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answers to each of the points.

1 - WSGIDaemonProcess/WSGIProcessGroup indicate that mod_wsgi should fork of a separate process for running the WSGI application in. This is a fork only and not a fork/exec, so mod_wsgi is still in control of it. When it is detected that a URL maps to a WSGI application running in daemon mode, then mod_wsgi code in the Apache child worker processes will proxy the request details through to the daemon mode process where the mod_wsgi code there reads it and calls up into your WSGI application.

2 - Yes, multiple requests can be operating concurrently and be wanting to modify the module global data at the same time.

3 - For the time that execution is within Python itself then no, they aren't strictly running in parallel as the global interpreter lock means that only one thread can be executing Python code at a time. The Python interpreter will periodically switch which thread is getting to run. If one of the threads calls into C code and releases the GIL then at least for the time that thread is in that state it can run in parallel to other threads, running in Python or C code. As example, when calls are made down into the Apache/mod_wsgi layer to write back response data, the GIL is released. This means that the actual writing back of response data at the lower layers is not prevent other threads from running.